# Community for VoIP telephony

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have taken a look at all communities available at the Stack Exchange sites, but I couldn't find any community for discussing [VoIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) telephony.

What is the right place to post questions regarding VoIP telephony and the SIP protocol?

Example:

- Does the SIP protocol allow to transmit DTMF codes in-band or must they be filtered out and transmitted via a control/signalling channel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### What is the right place to post questions regarding VOIP telephony and the SIP protocol?

> Example:
>
> Does SIP protocol allow to transmit DTMF codes in-band or they must be filtered out and transmitted via control/signalling channel?

It looks like your question might be on topic on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com):

> design or theory of protocols used to operate a network (e.g. IP, TCP, routing protocols, STP, etc);
> content delivery networks;

It even has a [voip](/questions/tagged/voip) tag, https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/voip/info:

> For questions about Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) which encompasses various technologies (methods, functions, and encapsulations) for encoding and delivering audio on a network using IP.

[Super User](http://www.superuser.com) also has a [voip](/questions/tagged/voip) tag, https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/voip, but those questions are generally about device or software configuration and not so much about the protocols used:

> VoIP questions should cover configuration of softphones, voice software (such as Asterisk) that runs on computers (no hardphones or PBXs) or troubleshooting VoIP quality and connectivity issues by means of computer hardware or software (tcpdump, wireshark).

Note:

- It looks as though this question, [Troubleshooting One Way Audio](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10840/troubleshooting-one-way-audio), indirectly answers your example question.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic on [networkengineering.se].